# How get a excel sheet with its code name property with "python"

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to get a Excel's sheet with Python. I can do this with the sheet's name but I want get it with its Code Name property. The following is a code using the sheet's name:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb_donnees = load_workbook("Données.xlsm", read_only = True)
name_ws_1 = wb_donnees.get_sheet_name()[0]
ws_1 = wb_donnees[name_ws_1]
```

But I want get the sheet with its Code Name property. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: do you mean a variable? `filename = "Données.xlsm"; wb_donnees = load_workbook(filename,...)` then changing the hardcoded string to something dynamic.

Comment: For example, in the Excel's workbook _Données.xlsm_ I have a sheet with the name "Discretisation du problème" but the its Name Code property is "Discretisation". Well, I want to get the sheet with his Name Code and not with his Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should will only work if the file is not opened in read-only mode:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("Données.xlsm")
for n in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[n]
    print(n, ws.sheet_properties.codeName)
```

Answer (score 3):

Charlie Clark's answer works for me in read mode.

I'm not sure whether OP needed this, but when *writing* a new workbook, you cannot get the codename this way. Instead, you will need to specify it yourself, otherwise the function returns `None`, and sheets will only be codenamed 'Sheet1' etc at workbook creation.

```
wb = load_workbook('input.xlsm')
wsx = wb.create_sheet('New Worksheet')
wsx.sheet_properties.codeName = 'wsx'

wb.save('output.xlsm')
```